# Have I found a bug or made a mistake in pandas df.tail()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Ok, I've got a weird one. I might have found a bug, but let's assume I made a mistake first. Anyways, I am running into some issues with pandas.

I want to locate the two last columns of a dataframe to compare the values of column `'Col'`. I run the code inside a for loop because it needs to run on all files in a folder. This code:

```
import pandas

for item in itemList:
    df = df[['Col']].tail(2)
    valA = df.iloc[1]['Col']
    valB = df.iloc[0]['Col']
```

Works mostly. I ran it over 1040 data frames without issues. Then at 1041 of about 2000 it causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 206, in <module>
    valA = df.iloc[1]['Col']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1373, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1830, in _getitem_axis
    self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1713, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

From this I thought, the data frame might be too short. It shouldn't be, I test for this elsewhere, but ok, mistakes happen so let's `print(df)` to figure this out.
If I `print(df)` before the assignment of `.tail(2)` like this:

```
print(df)
df = df[['Col']].tail(2)
valA = df.iloc[1]['Col']
valB = df.iloc[0]['Col']
```

I see a data frame of 37 rows. In my world, 37 > 2.

Now, let's move the `print(df)` down one line like so:

```
df = df[['Col']].tail(2)
print(df)
```

The output is usually two lines as one would expect. However, at the error the `df.tail(2)` returns a single row of data frame out of a data frame with 37 rows. Not two rows, one row. However, this only happens for one item in the loop. All others work fine. If I skip over the item manually like so:

```
for item in itemList:
    if item == 'troublemaker':
        continue
```

... the script runs through to the end. No errors happen.

I must add, I am fairly new to all this, so I might overlook something entirely. Am I? Suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here's the output of `print(df)` in case of the error

```
                Col       
Date                  
2018-11-30        True
```

and in all other cases:

```
                Col       
Date
2018-10-31       False
2018-11-30        True
```

Comment: would you like show you df.tail(2) to us here ?

Comment: W-B, do you mean the output of it?

Comment: I mean show us the print(df.tail(2)), what is the output

Comment: Sure, W-B, done.

Comment: Adding a approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it does not have second index, that is why return the error , try using `tail` and `head` , be aware of this , for your sample df, `valA` and `valB` will be the same value

```
import pandas

for item in itemList:
    df = df[['Col']].tail(2)
    valA = df.tail(1)['Col']
    valB = df.head(1)['Col']
```

Comment: Thanks, you got me on track. The mistake is a bug elsewhere in the script which causes the data frame to be only one line, but only in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug since it only happens to one df in 2000. Can you show that df?
I also don't think you need tail here, have you tried

```
valA = df.iloc[-2]['Col']
valB = df.iloc[-1]['Col']
```

to get the last values.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I tried your way, and you are right, there is no need for tail().